# Simple Python Temp Script

Tags: python, function, scope, temp

I have written a very simple temp script that will prompt the user for input and spit out an answer. As you can see below, I prompt the user to enter 1,2, or 3. 1 being fah to cel, 2 being cel to feh, and 3 to exit the program. If the user enters 1 or 2, another prompt will ask them to enter the degrees they want converted. This entry is saved in variable:

```
scale
```

My functions I have written should calculate the float into the proper conversion and loop back to the main menu after the correct temp is printed. There is some logic in the try/except statement that will attempt to convert this input into a float, and if it can't, it will print a nasty gram. When I run this code, everything seems to work fine until it gets to the function call fahtoCel:

```
fc = fahtoCel(scale)
```

I am pretty sure I have all the indenting correct and have studied declaring functions and calling them within the script. My only suspicion would be my function call is within my try/except statement and perhaps that the scope is incorrect? My code:

```
def fahtoCel(number):
    return(number - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)

while True:
    x = raw_input("""Please enter 1,2 or 3: """)
    if x == "3":
        exit(0)
    if x == "1":
        scale = raw_input("""Enter degrees in Fah: """)
        try:
            scale = float(scale)
            fc = fahtoCel(scale)
        except:
            print("Invalid Entry")
        continue
    print("%.2f degrees fah equals %.2f degrees Cel" % (scale, fc))
    if x == "2":
    #Do the same for cel to fah#
```

Comment: Well, what is the error you actually get? You should post the traceback.

Comment: Code works as expected for me. You don't get any output, but then you don't try to print the value of `fc`, because you call `continue` which causes your `print` call to be skipped over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`continue` transfers execution to the beginning of the `while` loop, so you never reach your `print` statement, regardless of the outcome of the `try` statement. You need to indent it further:

```
try:
    scale = float(scale)
    fc = fahtoCel(scale)
except Exception:  # Don't use bare except! You don't want to catch KeyboardInterrupt, for example
    print("Invalid entry")
    continue
print("%.2f degrees fah equals %.2f degrees Cel" % (scale, fc))
```

Really, though, your `try` statement is too broad. The only exception you should worry about catching is the `ValueError` that `float` might raise.

```
try:
    scale = float(scale)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid entry")
    continue
fc = fahtoCel(scale)
print("%.2f degrees fah equals %.2f degrees Cel" % (scale, fc))
```

Comment: Well, I did screw up the indentation after all! Thanks for the feedback! After I indented further, I was able to get the correct output. Would the ValueError catch if the user accidentally pressed the enter key instead of entering a valid number?

Comment: Yes; an empty string is just one more invalid floating-point literal.